# connection using odbc connect issue

Tags: php, sql, odbc

I am using this in order to print all names of a specific table in a sql server and here is the code:

```
$host="";
$uid="";
$passVal="";
$database="montim";
odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server};Server=$host;Database=$database;",$uid, $passVal ) or die("Connection could not established");
$query = "SELECT * FROM users";
$res = odbc_exec($query) or die(odbc_error());
while( $row = odbc_fetch_array($res) ) {
print_r($row); 
}
```

I come up with this error:

```
 Warning: odbc_exec() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in
```

could someone please help me why is that?
I mean is simple as that, i'm not trying to do something complicated...
Thanks

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-exec.php

Answer (score 2):

[ODBC_EXEC](http://php.net/manual/de/function.odbc-exec.php) needs also a `connection_id`. Try

```
$connection = odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server};Server=$host;Database=$database;",$uid,    
...
$res = odbc_exec($connection, $query) or die(odbc_error());
```

Comment: You did not give `odbc_exec` the connection_id. And you did not store the connection_id from the connect method in a variable.

Comment: cAN I PLEASE ASK YOU SOMETHING!
the equivalent of mysql_real_escape_string with odbc..which is?
thanks!

Comment: Google it. And if you don't find an answer you can ask another question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: i googled it, i got something like use addslashes.. would it work?

Answer (score 0):

The ODBC functions do not implicitly remember the active connection behind the scenes the way the `mysql_` functions do. This is a good thing, BTW. You need to keep track of the connection and pass it around:

```
$con = odbc_connect(...);
odbc_exec($con, ...);
```

Please read the manual and pay attention to the necessary parameters: http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-exec.php

Comment: I got this, i got this :)
i'm so happy!
Thanks!